# How to index without triggering 'IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.' error

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to find the maximum value(s) in a dictionary and my approach is to iterate through and check for the greatest values and make a list of the greatest value/key pair and anything equivelent to it from a dictionary and I have the following...

```py
def foo(class_sum, input_object):  # Predicts the class x is a member of given probability dictionary
    probabilities = calc_class_probs(class_sum, input_object)  # Returns a dictionary with probability elements
    best_label, best_perc = list(), list()
    best_perc.append(-1)
    print(best_perc[0])
    for val in probabilities:
        print(probabilities[val])
        if probabilities[val] > best_perc[0]:
            del best_label
            del best_perc  # Empty list in case unwanted elements are present
            best_label, best_perc = val, probabilities[val]  # update with new best
        elif probabilities[val] == best_perc:
            best_label.append(val)
            best_perc.append(probabilities[val])

    return best_label, best_perc
```

So from this I expect that `if probabilities[val] > best_perc[0]:` will evaluate to  `7.591391076586993e-36 > -1`, at least for the first iteration. However I get the following output from the print statements...

```py
-1
7.591391076586993e-36
```

EDIT: it appears to fail on the second iteration, could this be due to the `del` statements?

```py
0 7.591391076586993e-36
1 7.297754873023128e-36
...
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

and this error...

```py
if probabilities[val] > best_perc[0]:
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Why can it print the values but not index them here? Please note `probabilities` is a dictionary with keys that have single probability values like the below.

`{'0': 7.59139e-36, '1': 7.2977e-36,...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
best_label, best_perc = val, probabilities[val]
```

After executing first 'if' `best_lavel` and `best_perc` is no longer list, so you cant access `best_perc[0]`.

You can replace it by

```
best_label, best_perc = [val], [probabilities[val]]
```

Notice, when you iterate in a dictionary, you iterate through keys, not values.
You can alos iterate by keys and values:

```
for key, val in dictionary.items():
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about iterating through dictionaries, solved and improved my code!